# Using multiple values for iQuery method .css() throws error: 'missing )'. However its not missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Error says I'm missing a parenthesis. However the syntax is identical to w3Schools and Mozilla. .css() works if im only setting one style, but break when setting more than 1.

jQuery

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready( function(){

          // event-handler to create new element
          function createContainer() {

              // variables store values from <select> element
              var elementType = $('select').val();

              // string containing markup for use with .append()
              var elementTypeStr = $(` <${elementType}> This is a ${elementType} </${elementType}> `);
              // this throws error, while setting single style doesn't
              $('#layout_demo').append( elementTypeStr );
              elementTypeStr.css("background-color":" blue" , "height": "100px");

          } // end createContainer()

          // ---------------------------- event handlers ---------------------

          $('#btn').click( createContainer );
          // button to delete latest element or selected element

      }); // end ready

  </script>
```

HTML:

```
<section id="form">
  <!-- select element --->
  <label for="container"> Please select type of container to add</label>
  <select id= "container">
    <option value= "div" > &ltdiv&gt </option>
    <option value= "p"> &ltp&gt </option>
    <option value= "section"> &ltsection&gt </option>

  </select>
  <!-- Seperate container to hold now elements -->

  <button id="btn" > Create Container </button>
</section>

<div id="layout_demo">



</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `.css()` you have two options for passing arguments: comma separated strings or **Object literal notation**

therefore:

```
.css("background-color", " blue").css("height", "100px");
```

or rather:

```
.css({backgroundColor:"blue" , height:"100px"});
```

Also, instead of using `$('select').val();` use a stricter selector like some ID; `'select'` could be any select in your page.

```js
jQuery($ => {

  const createElement = () => {

    const tagName = $('#element').val();
    
    return $(`<${tagName}/>`, {
      appendTo: '#layout',
      text: `This is a ${tagName}`,
      css: {
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        height: "100px"
      },
    });

  }

  $('#create').on('click', createElement);

});
```

```html
<section id="form">
  <label>
    Please select type of container to add
    <select id="element">
      <option value="div">&ltdiv&gt</option>
      <option value="p">&ltp&gt</option>
      <option value="section">&ltsection&gt</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <button id="create">Create Container</button>
</section>
<div id="layout"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @CristiánOrmazábal missing bracket has been fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple `.css()` properties need to be inside an Object.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // event-handler to create new element
  function createContainer() {

    // variables store values from <select> element
    var elementType = $('select').val();

    // string containing markup for use with .append()
    var elementTypeStr = $(` <${elementType}> This is a ${elementType} </${elementType}> `);
    // this throws error, while setting single style doesn't
    $('#layout_demo').append(elementTypeStr);
    elementTypeStr.css({
      "background-color": " blue",
      "height": "100px"
    });

  } // end createContainer()

  // ---------------------------- event handlers ---------------------

  $('#btn').click(createContainer);
  // button to delete latest element or selected element

}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="form">
  <!-- select element --->
  <label for="container"> Please select type of container to add</label>
  <select id="container">
    <option value="div"> &ltdiv&gt </option>
    <option value="p"> &ltp&gt </option>
    <option value="section"> &ltsection&gt </option>

  </select>
  <!-- Seperate container to hold now elements -->

  <button id="btn"> Create Container </button>
</section>

<div id="layout_demo">



</div>
```